# Understanding the mathematics of batch training in neural networks

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tensor

When I am doing batch training, say *Mini-batch Gradient Descent* for example, how does the network feed itself with the batch data? To be specific, at each step (when there is one batch as input), does the network

1) take the **whole batch** (a fixed number of images, i.e. a 4D input tensor) per step and process **one example** (an image) to calculate gradients which will be averaged after iterating the batch or

2) process the **whole batch** and calculate the gradients directly?

A simple example of CNN on MNIST job (with some unnecessary codes removed):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.utils.data as Data     # Batch training
import torchvision                  # Dataset API
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Hyper parameters
EPOCH = 1
BATCH_SIZE = 50
LR = 0.001
DOWNLOAD_MNIST = False

# Download dataset
train_data = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
    root='./mnist',
    train=True,  # False: test data
    transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),    # value(0,1)
    download=DOWNLOAD_MNIST
)

# Batch data loader
train_loader = Data.DataLoader(
    dataset=train_data,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    shuffle=True,
    num_workers=2
)

# Test data
test_data = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
    root='./mnist',
    train=False
)
test_x = torch.unsqueeze(test_data.data, dim=1).type(
    torch.FloatTensor)[:2000]/255
test_y = test_data.targets[:2000]


# CNN
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(  # (1,28,28)
                in_channels=1,  # Gray
                out_channels=16,    # Silmultaneous filters
                kernel_size=5,
                stride=1,
                # Filled with zeros if stride=1,padding=(kernel_size-1)/2
                padding=2,
            ),    # -> (16,28,28)
            nn.ReLU(),  # -> (16,28,28)
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),    # -> (16,14,14)
        )
        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(   # (16,14,14)
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 5, 1, 2),  # -> (32,14,14)
            nn.ReLU(),  # -> (32,14,14)
            nn.MaxPool2d(2)  # -> (32,7,7)
        )
        self.out = nn.Linear(32*7*7, 10)  # Flattened -> 10 classes

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)   # (batch,32,7,7)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)   # (batch,32*7*7)
        output = self.out(x)
        return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cnn = CNN()
    # print(cnn)
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(cnn.parameters(), lr=LR)
    loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()   # The target is not one-hot
    loss_his = []

    # Training
    for epoch in range(EPOCH):
        for step, (x, y) in enumerate(train_loader):  # Extract tensors
            output = cnn(x)
            loss = loss_func(output, y)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            loss_his.append(loss.data)
```

Personally, I prefer the first description and I think the neural network can not take in a 2D tensor at a time. Am I correct in this stuff?

Comment: In pytorch you define how to update the gradients and the optimizer. Please provide a complete, minimal, example of some batched training which you're having questions about.

Comment: Hi jodag! Thank you for the advice and I have updated the question.

Comment: Vectorization is used for efficiency, i.e. the computations at each layer are done on the whole batch (which is just a 4D tensor).

Comment: @AndreasK. is right. Whether you process each item in the batch individually and accumulate gradients or compute it all at once is an implementation decision; the gradient over the batch will be the sum of the gradients for individual elements. But vectorization is faster.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Vectorization is really a great tool for the computation in the neural network.